# Object Detection using YOLO : get count of each detected object

Tags: python, object-detection

I am using YOLO to identify objects which is working fine however, I want to get count of the vehicles identified and to apply some `calc_pollution` further.
I am using below code however, I am getting error : `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple` for the line : `L = [labels.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(v_labels[0]) if v_scores[0,index] > 0.1]`

```
# correct the sizes of the bounding boxes for the shape of the image
correct_yolo_boxes(boxes, image_h, image_w, input_h, input_w)
# suppress non-maximal boxes
do_nms(boxes, 0.5)
# define the labels
labels = ["person", "bicycle", "car", "motorbike", "aeroplane", "bus", "train", "truck",
    "boat", "traffic light", "fire hydrant", "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench",
    "bird", "cat", "dog", "horse", "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe"]
# get the details of the detected objects
v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores = get_boxes(boxes, labels, class_threshold)
# summarize what we found
for i in range(len(v_boxes)):
    print(v_labels[i], v_scores[i])
# draw what we found
draw_boxes(photo_filename, v_boxes, v_labels, v_scores)
# Filtering results
L = [labels.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(v_labels[0]) if v_scores[0,index] > 0.1]
M=[]
vehicles=['car','bus','truck','motorcycle','auto-rickshaw']
for i in L:
  if i['name']in vehicles:
    M.append(i['name'])
S=set(M)
text=''
car=motorcycle=truck=bus=auto_rickshaw=0
for i in S:
  if i == 'car': car += M.count(i)
  if i == 'motorcycle': motorcycle += M.count(i)
  if i == 'truck': truck += M.count(i)
  if i == 'bus': bus += M.count(i)
  if i == 'auto-rickshaw' : auto_rickshaw += M.count(i)
  text+=str(i +' : '+ str(M.count(i))+"\t" )
print('Vehicles Identified -',text)
calc_pollution(car, motorcycle, truck, bus, auto_rickshaw)
```

If the output is:

```
bus 81.93148970603943
car 93.13983917236328
person 96.04818820953369
bus 73.79281520843506
person 95.54129242897034
person 98.43629598617554
person 91.06931686401367
person 93.62558126449585
person 72.36307859420776
```

for the image
[image: object detected image]
then I am expecting it to displayed as

Vehicles Identified - car : 1
bus : 2
truck : 0
motorcycle : 0
auto-rickshaw : 0

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is v_scores a list of nested lists? Is so, you would need to change this part  `v_scores[0,index]` to something like `v_scores[0][index]`

If that doesn't work, please share more information about the contents of v_boxes, v_labels, and v_scores.

Comment: thanks for your reply. v_boxes is the e.g. `<__main__.BoundBox object at 0x7fc10c362590>`, v_labels are the detected object like `car, bus, etc.` and v_scores is `81.93148970603943` for `bus`

Comment: You need to change this part. v_scores[0,index] that is not valid python syntax. You didn't quite explain what v_scores is. But maybe you just need to do this v_scores[index]

Comment: I have modified my question. The score is nothing but the value of detected object. For example, if the object is detected as bus then it might score it as 81.93148970603943